# Displacement on object stops it from using emission to light scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, displacement

**CHECK EDIT**

So I've finished work on one of my scenes for my year 12 animation, I wanted to use displacement on the hole that my character is falling down, but when I use it black sections appear everywhere.

With Displacement:
[image]

Without Displacement:
[image]
Does anyone have any idea what is causing this? They don't appear in view port rendering

Thanks,

**EDIT:**

Woops I worked out what the issue was just after posting this my particles system mesh was showing through the compositing >.>. Although now my issue has changed, now the Hole doesn't have any emission when I use the displacement.

Here's after displacement:

[image]

Any Ideas?

I'm using the displacement modifier with a noise texture to create the distortions in the tunnel. The coordinates of the texture is controlled by an empty so I can animate it warping and shifting. The node setup for the material is extensive but is mainly comprised of mixing generated textures:

Full Setup:
[image]

This is the important part though, the emission at the end which for some reason isn't showing through. I however doubt that it is the materials fault since the scene is lit properly from view port rendering.

[image]

Modifiers:

[image]

So I've managed to narrow it down to the animating of the displacement as the cause of no emission. When I have the empty moving to animate the displacement it no longer emits light and I have no idea why :C

Comment: It is very hard to understand the issue without more information. Please show the material nodes for whatever it is that you call "portal" and explain how you are approaching the "displacement". Don't skimp on the information.

Comment: Info has been added

Comment: If you suspect that the animating of the displacement is stopping the emission you should try replicating it in a much simpler example. Either you’ll see the same behaviour (in which case it will be easier for someone to pick this up and try and help) or it will work correctly - in which case that wasn’t cause and there’s something different in your ‘broken’ situation.